# how we can compare objects of two class by using 'Equals' keyword?

Tags: c#

Can I compare objects of two class by using `Equals`??

```
public class class1
    { }
public class class2
    { }
class1 obj1=new class1();
class2 obj2=obj1;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You're assigning with `=` not comparing

Comment: `Equals` is not a "keyword"; `=` is not an equality operator (`==` is).

Comment: `Equals()` is a method, not a keyword. And `=` is assignment, not equality test. You may need a C# primer before you go much further.

Answer (score 8):

See [Overloading Equals operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx)

EDIT:

On second thought, I think you are look for the [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You would compare the objects using something like:

```
bool areEqual = obj1 == obj2;

// Or

bool areEqual = obj1.Equals(obj2);

// Or

bool areEqual = object.Equals(obj1, obj2);
```